# JS: Variable (array) outside the loop - what happened?

Tags: javascript

Could you please kindly correct what I've done wrong?

```
var ipLocations = []; // variable in question

for (i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {

            $.getJSON(....

};

alert(ipLocations); // becoming '' here:(
```

Why ipLocations is `''` here?

Comment: hey... dont be mean... tell what is wrong??

Comment: what is it that is wrong??

Answer (score 2):

The code inside your for-loop is a non-blocking code... meaning your alert will fire way before your both `getJSON` and `setTimeout` callbacks populate `ipLocations`.

You can fix it by using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or a callback function for your `getJSON` function which would check if all the requests were finished, and if so, show the alert.